# How do I get order details by order number not by order id [woocommerce-rest-api] [python]

Tags: python, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to get the order details through the woocommerce-rest-api with the order number (in JSON response field 'number') instead of the order id. How can I achieve this?

As I understood it wcapi.get("orders?number=JZ-31") should work, but I get several orders instead of the one with the number "JZ-31" ("JZ-31" is included in the response as many others also). I guess it's interpreted like wcapi.get("orders"). That's why I get several order instead of the specific one. With the ID it works without problems, but I want it with the order number.

```py
wcapi.get("orders?number=JZ-31") # Did not work
wcapi.get("orders", params={"number" : "JZ-31"}) # Did not work
```

I expect that I get a response with containing exactly one order with the order number I pass. But I am actually getting all orders. As I said if I use the order id it's working without problems but I need to get the orders by the order number.

Comment: I saw your issue on GitHub, were you able to find a solution to this?